# How to check if object with equal value is in a container in logarithmic time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I want to see if an object with equal value is in a container in logarithmic time.

I would like to have the following functionality:

```
const a = [];

const el1 = {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'};
const el2 = {name: 'name2', directive: 'directive2'};
const el3 = {name: 'name3', directive: 'directive3'};
const b = {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'};

a.push(el1);
a.push(el2);
a.push(el3);


if(a.some(el => (el.name === b.name && el.directive === b.directive ))) {
  console.log("YES!");
} else {
  console.log("NO!");
}
```

This gives me the result I want. However, this is O(N) time.

```
const s = new Set();

const el1 = {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'};
const el2 = {name: 'name2', directive: 'directive2'};
const el3 = {name: 'name3', directive: 'directive3'};
const b = {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'};

s.add(el1);
s.add(el2);
s.add(el3);

if(s.has(b)) {
  console.log("YES!");
} else {
  console.log("NO!");
}
```

This is O(logN), but the result is not what I want.

So what kind of Javascript datastructure could I use that would print `YES` in the above code and would have complexity O(logN)? (I don't want to implement a datastructure myself)

Comment: What makes you assume there is one?

Comment: I'm asking if there is one. I would assume there is since this seems to be a very generic use case.

Comment: How about if your data is already sorted and you did a binary search?

Comment: Your requirements are possible, but giving the best approach would require more information about the kind of objects you allow. Are they always just shallow arrays containing plain objects with strings for values?

Comment: It returns false because they (`el1` and `b`) are different object references. You can fill the `b` by `el1`.

Comment: You need a different container structure, such as a sorted list or B-tree.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts. sorry, I changed the syntax now. I'm quite surprised the old syntax worked in my repl, but anyway that's another topic

Comment: @octavian it worked because `b.name === undefined`, but if you wrote it that way it probably logged `NO!`

Comment: Are you looking to solve for this specific `[{name, directive}]` case or for a more general one?

Comment: @octavian, test [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589796/how-to-check-if-object-with-equal-value-is-in-a-container-in-logarithmic-time/#48589940). It is easy and works well as `O(logN)` and _you can use it with any object_ easily.

Comment: Is it possible to have two or more objects that have the same name?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Map keyed by name, where the corresponding value is a Set of directives:

```js
const elements = [
    {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'},
    {name: 'name2', directive: 'directive2'},
    {name: 'name3', directive: 'directive3'}
];

const map = new Map(elements.map(({name}) => [name, new Set]));
elements.forEach(({name, directive}) => map.get(name).add(directive));

const b = {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'};

if (map.has(b.name) && map.get(b.name).has(b.directive)) {
    console.log("YES!");
} else {
    console.log("NO!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: the array `a` is sorted lexicographically, i.e. `a[i]<a[j]` whenever `a[i].name<a[j].name || (a[i].name==a[j].name && a[i].description<a[j].description))`

Here's a binary search with logarithmic complexity:

```js
const a = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  si = String(i);
  el = {
    name: 'name' + si,
    directive: 'directive' + si
  };
  a.push(el);
}

const b = {
  name: 'name70000',
  directive: 'directive70000'
};


var c = 0; // counter 

// binary search
function binary_search(a, b) {
  c++;
  var l = 0;
  var r = a.length - 1;
  if (l > r) {
    return false;
  }
  m = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);
  if ((a[m].name < b.name) || (a[m].name == b.name && a[m].directive < b.directive)) {
    return binary_search(a.slice(m + 1), b);
  } else if ((a[m].name > b.name) || (a[m].name == b.name && a[m].directive > b.directive)) {
    return binary_search(a.slice(0, m), b);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}



found = binary_search(a, b);
console.log(found, "in " + String(c) + " steps");
```

Comment: Optimal performance is not necessarily logarithmic time though, right?

Comment: @JasonB in general, no. If the array is *sorted* you could do a binary search to have logarithmic complexity

Answer (score 0):

We could use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) as a data-structure. Consider that we can employ a recursive logarithmic-time function both for sorting (or finding the position of insertion/deletion) along multiple dimensions by ascertaining the endpoints of the parent-field section and recursing.

Let's say our dimensions are scaffolded: `name -> directive -> third_property`

First sort the array according to `name`. Now find each `name` section in `log n` time and quicksort only that section according to `directive`, similarly for `third_property`. Then to find an element, use a similar binary search, first finding the range of the `name` property, then employing binary search within that range on `directive` and so on.

Or simply bypass all that by creating a key for each element that we can sort by and binary search on: `element.key = element.name + element.directive` :)

Answer (score -2):

> ***Don't look at the negative scores of this answer. Use it and enjoy. It's simple and works nice in `O(logN)`.***

---

It returns false because they (`el1` and `b`) are different object references. You can fill the `b` by `el1` but If you want a simple way to search with `O(logN)` you can use my following code:

```js
var orderObj = function(unordered){
   const ordered = {};
   Object.keys(unordered).sort().forEach(function(key) {
       ordered[key] = unordered[key];
    });
    return ordered;
}
Set.prototype.addIt = function(item){s.add(JSON.stringify(orderObj(item)));}
Set.prototype.hasIt = function(item){return s.has(JSON.stringify(orderObj(item)));}
    
//-------------------------------------

const s = new Set();

const el1 = {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'};
const el2 = {name: 'name2', directive: 'directive2'};
const el3 = {name: 'name3', directive: 'directive3'};

const b = {name: 'name1', directive: 'directive1'};
const c = {directive: 'directive3', name: 'name3'};

s.addIt(el1);
s.addIt(el2);
s.addIt(el3);

s.hasIt(b)
 ?console.log("YES!")
 :console.log("NO!");

s.hasIt(c)
 ?console.log("YES!")
 :console.log("NO!");
```

---

**Update:**

I Updated my answer, now **it support the objects with different orders**. As you can see in the above example `c` has a different order against `el3` but the script return `Yes` result ;)

Comment: I think the OP is aware of this, but needs it to work when `b` is a different object with the same property values.

Comment: As to your updated solution based on JSON: be aware that object properties may come out in a different stringified order, yet semantically property order is not relevant for JavaScript objects, and so even then they should be regarded as matching.

Comment: @trincot I don't think this is a good solution generally but couldn't we sort the JSON string before inserting and querying?